# Wordpress latest News integrate on two websites

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want a wordpress plugin that show latest news on two website if i update any news from my website it should update on different website as well as is there any plugin available for wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept or [RSS feed](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) in WordPress. For that, [RSS Post Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-post-importer/) plugin will help you.

For more information,

- [Tutorial: How to show a list of blog posts from another site on your WordPress site](https://voxpopagency.com/blog/how-to-import-blog-post-from-rss-feed-to-wordpress-as-a-custom-post-type)
- [How to Fetch Feeds in WordPress Using WP RSS Aggregator](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-fetch-feeds-in-wordpress-using-wp-rss-aggregator/)
- [Everything You Need to Import and Display RSS Feeds with WordPress](https://problogger.com/everything-you-need-to-import-and-display-rss-feeds-with-wordpress/)

Hope this will helps you.